# Angular.js: Why is angular equals giving me different results?

Tags: angularjs

I have a function inside of a controller that tells me wether or not a resource has been changed, so that a server request will only be sent to save the object if there have been no changes. when the is clean function is called initially, it works fine. However, when it is called inside of another function, which is triggered by an `ng-click` event, I get a different result. Why would this be the case?

**Example Code**

```
app.controller('EditorController', ['$scope', 'Item' function($scope, Item) {
    $scope.item = Item.get({ id: 1});
    $scope.original = angular.clone(item);
    $scope.isClean = function() {
      return angular.equals($scope.item, $scope.original);
    }

    $scope.isClean(); //returns true

    $scope.save = function() {
       if($scope.isClean()) {  //is always false here
         return;
       }
       //etc..
    }
}]);
```

Comment: By any chance, is your Item.get an AJAX request?

Comment: It is worth noting that angular will do dirty checking for you on forms simply add the [ng-form](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form) directive. Then you can use ` $scope.item.$dirty` to check for a dirty model.

Comment: @JonathanPalumbo this isn't coming from a form, but thanks, that is good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have an asynchronous problem. Here's your code, explained:

```
$scope.item = Item.get({ id: 1}); // Until AJAX completes, $scope.item is undefined
$scope.original = angular.clone(item); // AJAX hasn't completed yet, this is a clone of undefined

$scope.isClean(); // Compares undefined to undefined, returns true

$scope.save = function() {
    if($scope.isClean()) { // AJAX has loaded, but original is not updated. Now we're comparing an object to undefined. 

    }
}
```

You need to specify a callback on your `.get` to update the original, like so:

```
$scope.item = Item.get({ id: 1 }, function(res) { 
    $scope.original = angular.clone($scope.item) // Could also use 'res'
});
```